# I can't pass this test in rspec. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
RSpec.describe "Fizz Buzz Tests" do
    it "should return `Fizz` for number divisible by 3" do
        expect(fizzBuzz(3)).to eq "Fizz"
    end

    it "should return `Buzz` for number divisible by 5" do
        expect(fizzBuzz(5)).to eq "Buzz"
    end

    it "should return `FizzBuzz` for number divisible by 3 and 5" do
        expect(fizzBuzz(15)).to eq "FizzBuzz"
    end

    it "should return `FizzBuzz` for number divisible by 3 and 5" do
        expect(fizzBuzz(90)).to eq "FizzBuzz"
    end

    it "should return 7 since it is indivisible by 3 and 5" do
        expect(fizzBuzz(7)).to eq 7
    end
end
```

And this is my code:

```
def fizz_buzz (number)
    if number%3==0&&number%5==0
      puts ("FizzBuzz")
    elsif number%3==0
      puts ("Fizz")
    elsif number%5==0
      puts ("Buzz")
    else
      puts (number)
  end
 end

 fizz_buzz(3)
 fizz_buzz(5)
 fizz_buzz(15)
 fizz_buzz(90)
 fizz_buzz(7)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fizzBuzz` method should return values, not print them.

```
require 'rspec'

def fizzBuzz(number)
  if number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0
    "FizzBuzz"
  elsif number % 3 == 0
    "Fizz"
  elsif number % 5 == 0
    "Buzz"
  else
    number
  end
end

RSpec.describe "Fizz Buzz Tests" do
  it "should return `Fizz` for number divisible by 3" do
    expect(fizzBuzz(3)).to eq "Fizz"
  end

  it "should return `Buzz` for number divisible by 5" do
    expect(fizzBuzz(5)).to eq "Buzz"
  end

  it "should return `FizzBuzz` for number divisible by 3 and 5" do
    expect(fizzBuzz(15)).to eq "FizzBuzz"
  end

  it "should return `FizzBuzz` for number divisible by 3 and 5" do
    expect(fizzBuzz(90)).to eq "FizzBuzz"
  end

  it "should return 7 since it is indivisible by 3 and 5" do
    expect(fizzBuzz(7)).to eq 7
  end
end
```